# Elementary problem with  Fibonacci numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory

I need help in proving one elementary result with Fibonacci numbers.
Prove that for $n>2$, the product $F_1 \cdot F_2 \cdots F_n$ cannot be a perfect square,
where $F_1 = F_2 = 1, F_{n+1}=F_n + F_{n-1}$.

Answer (score 12):

Take the largest prime $p$ up to $n$ (which is greater than $n/2$ by Bertrand's postulate) and notice that since the Fibonacci sequence is a divisibility sequence: $gcd(F_p,F_k)=F_{gcd(p,k)}=1$ for $k\neq p$ then if $\prod F_k$ is a perfect square so is $F_p$, but according to [this theorem](http://math.la.asu.edu/~checkman/SquareFibonacci.html#th3) the only non-trivial square in the Fibonacci sequence is 144 and so you get the result.

Remark: The paper ["Diophantine equations with products of consecutive terms in Lucas sequences"](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6WKD-4DS6T99-1&_user=10&_coverDate=10%2F31%2F2005&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=search&_origin=search&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_searchStrId=1459684324&_rerunOrigin=google&_acct=C000050221&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=10&md5=333ca08e7c10f183904e8dca4e124de3&searchtype=a) by F. Luca, T.N. Shorey determines all products of consecutive Fibonacci numbers which are perfect powers.

Comment: Thank you! Although I am sure that this question should be more elementary than the COHN Theorem, which was open question for decades...

Comment: Interestingly, from elementery identity F_{n+1}*F_{n-1} - F_n^2 = (-1)^n it follows (without COHN Theorem) that F_{n+1} and F_{n-1} cannot be both exact squares, so if we would have prime p and p+2 greater than n/2, the same agrument would finish the proof ... But twin prime conjecture is a little bit harder than COHN Theorem :)

Comment: I haven't thought about this much, but I couldn't find something simpler. Do you have any reason to believe the problem has an elementary solution?

Comment: Yes, I have. It is in the book with problems for mathematical olympiads. I prepare high-school students for olympiads and the next topic will be Fibonacci numbers, so I try to find appropriate problems.

Comment: The link to `sciencedirect.com` is broken, but the article can be found at [doi:10.1016/j.jnt.2004.08.007](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jnt.2004.08.007) ([Zbl 1081.11023](https://zbmath.org/1081.11023)).